# make_unique giving error 2248

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unique-ptr, c++14

I am having an issue with make_unique that I am at a loss with.

```
_replace_find = unique_ptr<Fl_Input>(new Fl_Input{ 80, 10, 210, 25, "Find:" });
_replace_find = make_unique<Fl_Input>(Fl_Input{ 80, 10, 210, 25, "Find:" });
```

when I use the make_unique line it gives me this error, but when I use the other it compiles just fine.  From my understanding make_unique pretty much does the same thing, but is exception safe.

```
Error   1   error C2248: 'Fl_Widget::Fl_Widget' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Fl_Widget'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\fl\fl_input_.h   488 1   hayley
```

I couldn't find anything with that error dealing with make_unique or unique_ptr on SO. I wouldn't be asking this otherwise.

as always thank you for your time and advice.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is that your new code is calling the copy constructor.

Comment: @Brian Or move constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably wanted to write

```
std::make_unique<FlInput>(80, 10, 210, 25, "Find:")
```

instead of

```
std::make_unique<FlInput>(FlInput{80, 10, 210, 25, "Find:"})
```

It seems the class `FlInput` has a private copy and/or move constructor making the second form illegal.

Comment: Thank you! this was the issue.

Answer (score 5):

```
_replace_find = unique_ptr<Fl_Input>(new Fl_Input{ 80, 10, 210, 25, "Find:" });
_replace_find = make_unique<Fl_Input>(Fl_Input{ 80, 10, 210, 25, "Find:" });
```

Those lines are not equivalent.

The first line creates an `Fl_input` on the free store, and then initializes a `unique_ptr` with it.
The second creates a temporary `Fl_input` and calls `make_unique<Fl_input>` with it, which creates a new instance on the free store by calling the copy/move ctor (which is obviously inaccessible, thus the error).

What you wanted is giving all the ctor-arguments to `make_unique<Fl_input>`:

```
_replace_find = make_unique<Fl_Input>(80, 10, 210, 25, "Find:");
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was the issue.  Since Dietmar answered just before you I marked his a the answer.  I up voted your answer too as it was well explained.